# readonly property in RubyMotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rubymotion

if this in obj-c

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* name;

@end

@implementation SomeClass

@synthesize name;

//If we want to implement our own setter to do something
- (void)setName(NSString*)aString {
    name = aString;
}

@end
```

is this in rubymotion

```
class SomeClass < NSObject
  attr_accessor :name

  #If we want to implement our own setter to do something
  def name=(aString)
    @name = aString
  end
end
```

How (and is it even possible) to create a `@property (nonatomic,strong, readonly)`?

And where can I read about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
attr_reader :name
```

This will only generate the getter method. You can read about this in the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader)